# How to scroll to first error in Magento 1.9 product page?

Tags: magento-1.9, validation, form-validation, prototype-js

Hi guys I would like to scroll to the first erroneous input on the product page. Currently it doesn't and stays at the bottom.

You then have to manually scroll up till you see the swatch option group that is not selected. So, no visual cue to show at bottom.

I  tried  to run a on DOMNodeInserted function  to see if it has class validation-advice. And if so run the scroll to element.

Didn't works as expected.

So would anyone how know to edit the validation script bottom of product view page in rwd theme or validation.js in magento-root/js/varien/prototype to scroll to the first input/ swatch where this is required is shown.

UPDATE:

Using the answer below I attempted to scroll to the first error (First element element without swatch select).

But, it doesn't work, as previous validation is still being used thus add to cart has to be pressed twice, logically working one step back.

```
console.log(jQuery(".validation-advice:not([style])"));
```

Using this line I logged the following:

[image: console log for error]

Showing that first submit returns no element, even though on purpose iv'e selected no swatches, so every option has error. Second submit picks up the error elements. Then I have chosen a swatch for the first option and pressed add to cart again, still it hasn't picked up that the first element no longer has error, the second submit picks it up. This trend continues throughout.

Is the else in the wrong place ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit product template: /app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

find:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            } 
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

add

```
else {
      // do what you need to do e.g. scrollTop();
      // or scroll to id
      }
```

before

```
}.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

Complete code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        var productAddToCartForm = new VarienForm('product_addtocart_form');
        productAddToCartForm.submit = function(button, url) {
            if (this.validator.validate()) {
                var form = this.form;
                var oldUrl = form.action;

                if (url) {
                   form.action = url;
                }
                var e = null;
                try {
                    this.form.submit();
                } catch (e) {
                }
                this.form.action = oldUrl;
                if (e) {
                    throw e;
                }

                if (button && button != 'undefined') {
                    button.disabled = true;
                }
            } else {
                // do what you need to do e.g. scrollTop();
            }
        }.bind(productAddToCartForm);
```

That's all.

[Edit]

To achieve what you need just add before productAddToCartForm.submit

```
var myFormValidation = new Validation('product_addtocart_form');
//watch for select change
    $j(".super-attribute-select").on("change", function() {
    // check if .validation-failed class exist to prevent form validation before user click add to cart
    if ($j('.validation-failed').length ) {
          if ( !myFormValidation.validate()) {
            //form not validated,do your scroll stuff here.
           } else {
            //form is validated. remove this else if not needed
          }

    }
    });
```

Comment: This has put me on the right path: I just need to pick up the first erroneous input. I  tried `var thefirsterror = $j('.validation-advice:first')[0].id;` but magento just hides the first error, when corrected. So won't work correctly.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want to acomplish (sorry my english has seen better days) but if you need to target first erroneous select just find the first one with validation-failed class. However after you choose proper value for one option it doesn't autovalidate, you need to press Add To Cart. If you need to autovalidate selected option you need to write custom js function checking for select change.

Comment: I have this code in the else part: `var thefirsterror = $j('.validation-failed:first').attr("id");
        var theadvice = $j("#advice-required-entry-"+ thefirsterror);
        $j('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $j(theadvice).offset().top
       }, 2000);
` That works but only on second click, is there a way to fire it after it has validated, instead of second click ?

Comment: It fires on click because validation is run after submitting the form ( productAddToCartForm.submit ). To achieve what you want you need to write second js function where you need to check if there are .validation-failed (we need to give users a chance to select  options and click submit without executing validation.). After that you need to execute validation and if the form doesnt validate do your stuff (scrolling). Something like

Comment: I exceedeed 5 minutes allowed for edit in prevoius comment so here is part two :) So you need to check if 'validation-failed' exists and on select change execute validation (you can target selects with 'super-attribute-select' class) and if the form doesnt validate do your stuff (scrolling). If you need sample code let me know in comment

Comment: Sorry, I posted the solution I used but doesn't seem to have saved as I wasn't logged in. I just added a 300 ms to my scroll. Your way sounds better, could you provide me with the sample code please ?

Comment: Also, iv'e notice this code: `var inputBox = attr._e.optionSelect.up();
                    if (inputBox.hasClassName('validation-error')) {
                        inputBox.removeClassName('validation-error');
                        inputBox.down('.validation-advice').remove();
                    }` which isn't working I believe

Comment: Heyy Kaziko your code didn't work. :S

Comment: Should work. It's straight copy and paste from my default development instalation with RWD theme where it worked.  If you are using custom theme please check if classes I used exists in your theme. You can check working copy of this script here (my dev site): http://magento.mostcreative.pl/index.php/men/new-arrivals/chelsea-tee.html

Comment: Could it be because I am using swatches ? also I got it function correctly with,  setTimeout(function(){
     var thefirsterror = $j('.validation-failed:first').attr("id");
        var theadvice = $j("#advice-required-entry-"+ thefirsterror);
        $j('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $j(theadvice).offset().top - 165
       }, 800);
    }, 300)

Comment: Also, I have amended lines 410 to 415 in the swatches-product.js so on swatch selection correctly removes validation

Comment: Swatches are overlays for option select. But because selects are hidden with display:none we dont change them but script watches for select change

Comment: $j(".super-attribute-select").on("change", function() {

so you need to watch not for select change but swatch (target proper class)  click. 
And not to check for validation-failed class but for validation-advice class (red notification about error). 

So depending of swatch class (probably swatch-link) watch for click and here 
if ($j('.validation-failed').length ) {
change class to validation-advice.

Comment: Got it working with `var myFormValidation = new Validation('product_addtocart_form');
    $j(".swatch-link").click(function() {
    if ($j('.validation-advice').length ) {
          if ( !myFormValidation.validate()) {
             var thefirsterror = $j('.validation-failed:first').attr("id");
        var theadvice = $j("#advice-required-entry-"+ thefirsterror);
        $j('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $j(theadvice).offset().top - 165
       }, 800);
           }
    }
    });`